# Скругление уголков блока для IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Для блока заданы свойства

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; /* Для Firefox 3 */
-webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; /* Для Safari 4 и Chrome */
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0; /* Для современных браузеров */
```

как можно сделать так, чтобы уголки были скругленные и в IE?

Comment: Почему-то этот плагин он совсем перестал работать в ие, независимо от наличия или отсутствия text-align: center; :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Progressive Internet Explorer](http://www.xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/html5-and-css3/css3-pie.html)

Comment: Помогло, большое спасибо, но возникла проблема с выравниванием текста по центру. 
Уголки не скругляются в ие, если только у этих элементов есть свойство text-align: center; и если это свойтсво перенести в элемент-родитель - тоже.

Comment: Да, наверное надо было сразу сказать, что это не блочный элемент, а элементы списка ul li

Comment: Так сделайте его блочным, если это не вредит разметке

Comment: это меню, нет возможности оставить его списком?

Comment: Так пусть будет списком. Просто поставьте ему параметр inline-block или block

Comment: не помогло

Comment: Сложно сказть не зная структуры. Если я буду что-то советовать, то это будет "тыканье пальцем в небо". Незнаю, попробуйте внутри li текст обернуть в какой-нибуть тэг, например, **p** и уже для него задать text-align: center;